# How to change the view angle and label value of a chart .NET C#

Tags: c#, 3d, angle, pie-chart

## Short Description

I am using charts for a specific application where i need to change the view angle of the rendered 3D Pie chart and value of automatic labels from pie label names to corresponding pie values.

This how the chart looks:
[image: Pie Chart]

---

## Initialization

This is how i initialize it:

```
    Dictionary<string, decimal> secondPersonsWithValues = HistoryModel.getSecondPersonWithValues();
    decimal[] yValues = new decimal[secondPersonsWithValues.Values.Count]; //VALUES
    string[] xValues = new string[secondPersonsWithValues.Keys.Count]; //LABELS
    secondPersonsWithValues.Keys.CopyTo(xValues, 0);
    secondPersonsWithValues.Values.CopyTo(yValues, 0);
    incomeExpenseChart.Series["Default"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Pie;
    incomeExpenseChart.Series["Default"].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);
    incomeExpenseChart.ChartAreas["Default"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
    incomeExpenseChart.Series["Default"].CustomProperties = "PieLabelStyle=Outside";
    incomeExpenseChart.Legends["Default"].Enabled = true;
    incomeExpenseChart.ChartAreas["Default"].Area3DStyle.LightStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.LightStyle.Realistic;
    incomeExpenseChart.Series["Default"]["PieDrawingStyle"] = "SoftEdge";
```

Basically i am querying data from database using the `HistoryModel.getSecondPersonWithValues();` to get pairs as `Dictionary<string, decimal>` where *key* is the *person* and *value* is *ammount*.

---

## Problem #1

What i need is to be able to change the marked labels from *person names* to the *ammounts* or add another label of ammounts with the same colors (See Image).
[image]

---

## Problem #2

Another problem is that i need to change the view angle of 3D Pie chart. Maybe it's very simple and I just don't know the needed *property* or maybe i need to override some paint event. Either ways any kind of ways would be appriciated.

Thanks in advance George.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution for Problem #1

Adding new Label and filling with custom values helped.
In addition i changed the `Series.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;`

---

### Solution for Problem #2

I should have set the `ChartArea.Area3DStyle.IsClustered = true;` and then set the `ChartArea.Area3DStyle.Inclination;`

Comment: Nice... pretty nice... I was looking for the `Ìnclination` property. Doing `chart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Area3DStyle.Inclination = 50;` makes the Pie chart look way better! Thanks for sharing your findings! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `xlhart.Rotation` and `xlchart.Elevation`.